# Write the 3x3-Matrix A as product of elementary matrices ( rank(A)<3 )

Tags: matrices, gaussian-elimination

Notation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_matrix#Elementary_row_operations

$ a\in \mathbb{F}_{5}\\ A\in\mathbb{F}_{5}^{3x3}\\
A=\begin{pmatrix} a & a+1 & a+2 \\  a+1 & a+2 & a+3 \\ a+2 & a+3 & a+4\end{pmatrix}\\
L_{1,2}(-a)\cdot T_{1,2}\cdot L_{2,3}(-2)\cdot L_{1,3}(-1)\cdot L_{1,2}(-1) \cdot A=   \begin{pmatrix} 1&1&1 \\ 0&1&2 \\ 0&0&0 \end{pmatrix} \\ $

My problem is that I don't know how to continue. In the cases I studied before, I could always transform a matrix B with elementary row operations to this form: $E_{k}\cdot ... \cdot E_{1}\cdot B=I_{n}$ ,
in which $E_{i}$ is an random elementary matrix and $I_{n}$ the identity matrix. The next step I always took was $B=(E_{1})^{-1}\cdot ... \cdot(E_{k})^{-1} $ 
So I multiplied the inverse of every used elementary matrix from the left and then I only needed to compute the matrix multiplication.

But how can I write A as product of elementary matrices if rk(A)<3?

PS: I'm not used to write about math in english, please ask if something doesn't makes sense to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will end up with the identity matrix if and only if the original matrix was invertible. Yours was not :-)

To get to the reduced row echelon form, you would also need to multiply by $L_{2,1}(-1)$ in your notation, i.e. subtract row 2 from row 1, transforming row 1 to $(1,0,-1)$.

The end product would be simpler, but not an identity matrix still.

Comment: So every **non**- invertible matrix is **not** representable as a product of  elementary matrices ? And there are no exceptions?

Comment: @CherryBlossom1878 correct -- every elementary matrix is invertible, so a matrix is a product of elementary matrices only if it is invertible...